# Run specific method of the class defined by string

Tags: python

I have this sample code

```
class aaa:

    @staticmethod
    def method(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def method2(self):
        pass

command = 'method'
```

Now I would like to run method of the class aaa defined by command string. How could I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Static methods should not have a `self` parameter. Static methods do not interact with any class or instance attributes.

Answer (score 4):

Don't. There's rarely a reason to deal with the issues (security, cleaness, performance, arguably readability, ...) that this approach introduces. Just use `command = aaa.method`.

If you *have* to use a string (hopefully for a good reason), you *can* use `getattr` but you propably should use an explicit mapping specifying all valid names (this also makes the code future-proof against internal renaming/refactoring):

```
methods = {
    'method': aaa.method,
    'method2': aaa.method2,
}
methods[command]()
```

The case "no method for this string" can be handled like this:

```
method = methods.get(command)
if method is None:
    ... # handle error/bail out
```

Answer (score 3):

First, delete the `self` parameter of your `staticmethod`s - the whole point of `staticmethod`s is that they don't have a `self` parameter.  Then, use

```
method = getattr(aaa, command)
method()
```

or simply

```
getattr(aaa, command)()
```

to call the method named by `command`.

(I only wonder why you don't simply use `command = aaa.method` in the first place, but there are certainly applications where this is impossible.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr` to get an attribute of an object by name.

```
In [141]: class Foo(object):
   .....:     def frob(self):
   .....:         print "Frobbed"
   .....:         
   .....:         

In [142]: f = Foo()

In [143]: getattr(f, 'frob')
Out[143]: <bound method Foo.frob of <__main__.Foo object at 0x2374350>>

In [144]: _()
Frobbed
```